# How to get Push Notification working for ios using Gimbal Manager portal? I have done all necessary steps from Docs. Still No luck

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, gimbal

As per the Gimbal Dev Documentation I have followed all necessary steps for APNS support.

> Done with creating App Id, APNS Certificate, Provision Profile & all.

Also added Push Notification Certificate generated to Gimbal Manager [image: Gimbal Manager]

> Also Created valid Place & GeoFence entries. Please note that I am getting Reading when Beacon is near & also when enter/exit Geo Fence with all attributes but only when App is Running. Please note that I am also able to get deviceToken for my device & also calling Gimbal Method to set Push Notification Token

```
[Gimbal setPushDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

My Question is What is actual work around to Fire / Receive Push Notification? Am i missing something? Want to have push notification when beacon is detected or entered/left GeoFence. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have got satisfactory answer from Gimbal Manager.

> Thanks for your question.
>
> Developers can trigger notification when a user enter in a place(based
>   on Geofence or Beacons or Both) using "place based communication".
>   Place based communications gets delivered whenever there is a Place
>   Event (arrival or departure).
>
> Place based communications doesn't need PUSH certificate.
>
> Developers can set up Communication for newly created place(beacon) by
>   navigating to "Communicate" tab --> New Communication -->
>   Communication. You can setup Communication for all places or specific
>   place and when an app is in proximity of this place, a notification
>   will be received.
>
> Instant communication can be sent to all app users OR user who are
>   "IN" place(All or specific places). Instant communications are not
>   triggered when user enters a place.
>
> Please let us know if you have any queries.
>
> Thanks Ismail